# run vba script outlook server

Tags: vba, outlook, server-side

I have a sorting script in a shared outlook account, but it is only being executing when I open the outlook client.

Is there any way of create that script in the server and have it executing all the time?

Answer (score 1):

VBA scripts is a client's thing. It cannot be run without Outlook.

If you have an Exchange account configured in Outlook you may consider using EWS (Exchange Web Services). See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.